# Having trouble getting my error message to nest properly

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm having trouble getting the error message for when a user-entered value is equal to or less than zero to nest properly. I'm not sure where it should go, or if I need to do something else entirely. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code as it stands.

Instructions:
"A software company sells a package that retails for $99. Quantity discounts are given according to the following:" 10-19 = 20% Discount,20-49 = 30% Discount, 50-99 = 40% Discount, 100+  = 50% Discount.
Write a program that asks for the number of units purchased and computes the total cost of the purchase.
Input Validation: Decide how the program should handle an input of less than 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // needed for setprecision
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std; // need to use cout, cin, etc.

int main()
{
    double quantity, package = 99.00, initialPrice, discPrice, discount, calcDiscount, percent; // using double here because future multiplication by .2

    cout << "This program will calculate how much of a discount you may receive,\nbased on how many software packages you buy.\n\n";
    cout << "How many software packages do you intend to purchase?\n\n";
    cin >> quantity;

    {
        if (quantity <= 0)
            cout << "\nThat is not an acceptable amount. Please re-run the program with a amount greater than zero.\n\n";
    }

    if ( quantity >= 10 && quantity <= 19)
        discount = 0.2, percent = 20;
    else if ( quantity >= 20 && quantity <= 49)
        discount = 0.3, percent = 30;
    else if ( quantity >= 50 && quantity <= 99)
        discount = 0.4, percent = 40;
    else if ( quantity >= 100 )
        discount = 0.5, percent = 50;
    else if (quantity <10 && quantity >=1)
        discount = 0, percent = 0;

    {
        initialPrice = package * quantity;
        calcDiscount = (discount * package * quantity);
        discPrice = initialPrice - calcDiscount;
        cout << "\nThe total price for " << quantity << " software packages, minus a " << percent << "% discount of $";
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << calcDiscount << ",";
        cout << " is $" << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << discPrice << ".\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when someone enters a quantity of 19.5?

Comment: You have a whole bunch of extra curly braces. For example, your first `if` is wrapped in them for no reason. You're also wrapping a large chunk of code after your last `else if`. If that's all intended to happen with the last `else if`, then you must also include that first line. Otherwise, get rid of those curly braces.

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: I'm using "Starting out with C++ Early Objects" (Eighth Edition) by Tony Gaddis, Judy Walters, and Godfrey Muganda.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - I'm not sure what to do in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be fixed like this:

```
if (quantity <= 0)
{
     cout << "\nThat is not an acceptable amount. Please re-run the program with a amount greater than zero.\n\n";
     return -1;
}
else if ( quantity < 10)
    discount = 0, percent = 0;
else if ( quantity < 20)
    discount = 0.2, percent = 20;
else if ( quantity < 50)
    discount = 0.3, percent = 30;
else if ( quantity < 100)
    discount = 0.4, percent = 40;
else discount = 0.5, percent = 50;

initialPrice = package * quantity;
calcDiscount = (discount * package * quantity);
discPrice = initialPrice - calcDiscount;
cout << "\nThe total price for " << quantity << " software packages, minus a " << percent << "% discount of $";
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << calcDiscount << ",";
cout << " is $" << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << discPrice << ".\n\n";
```

Some other minor changes should be made to make code look better - its on you

Comment: Thank you, that really helped. Do you have an idea for how to deal with numbers that aren't whole? (Such as 19.5).